# PHP MySQL manipulating results?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
<?php
include_once('db.php');
session_start();

    $selectEmail = $db->prepare("SELECT `email` FROM `users` WHERE `uid` = :uid");

        $selectEmail->execute(array(':uid' => $_SESSION['uid']));

            $EmailRow = $selectEmail->fetch();  

                $UserEmail = $EmailRow['email'];

                    echo $UserEmail;

?>
```

I haven't actually written any code yet, nor am I asking for any code to be written.

This is more of a 'how would I do this' question.

Regardless, my question is: How can I manipulate results from MySQL?

For example: I select a user's e-mail address from the database w/PDO, and output it to a text-input so they see their e-mail, but replace the first three characters of it with stars so that when they try to change it I can verify they know the real e-mail address preventing accounts from being stolen.

I want to manipulate something like jmc@inbox.com to **c@inbox.com.

Is this possible, if so, how can I do it?

Comment: what about if the name@domain.com: if name is just three chars like info@example.com

Comment: I didn't mean LITERALLY 3 characters, it could be 1 or 2 if that part of the e-mail is short.  I just don't want it to be the part after @ because that's guessable.

Comment: so you need to setup your rules first

Comment: I want how to do it I don't need to get that specific yet.  Regardless if it was 3 chars it could block all of it and still be fine but I'd prefer it not to.  Are you just trying to disprove my idea or trying to help me?

Comment: ok its clear now, I just want you to discover how it would be in real scenario, I can only help you with the part that you can replace first three charactor with *

Comment: What does it to do with mysql? How a string `jmc@inbox.com` coming from mysql is different from string `jmc@inbox.com`coming from whatever else source?

Answer (score 0):

`I want to manipulate something like jmc@inbox.com to **c@inbox.com.`

You can try and play with this function [substr_replace function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php)

Comment: check my edits, for all intensive purposes that returns jmc@inbox.com.  How can I replace the first three characters?  Can you give me an example with that function?

Comment: `substr_replace($UserEmail , '*' , 0  , 2)` the result will be ***@inbox.com , in your scenario you need to have a line or function that will count the number of string of the email address and do the logic on how many *** you need to put on that string and put it on the 4th parameter of the function. I don't need to do all the work for you, we are on the same boat in learning :)

Comment: When I use that code it gives me http://puu.sh/3LSGf.png.  The e-mail is tester@hotmail.com.  In other words, it's eating up letters that should be shown.

Comment: im sorry the number of * is the length from 0 to 2 which is 3 , so 2nd parameter should be '***' , you may add this on the function that you're making.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. I have used proper comments in the code.

```
 $userEmail = "info@example.com";
 $len = strlen($userEmail); //Get the length of the email

 list($email, $domain) = explode('@', $userEmail); //Separate domain and mail

 $emailLength = strlen($email); //find mail length
 $maskLength = floor( $emailLength/2 ); //find the length of mask, half of the email length in this example
 $email = substr($userEmail, $maskLength, $len); //remove the characters that needs to be masked

 for($i = 0; $i < $maskLength; $i++){
    $mask .= '*';
 }

 $maskedEmail = $mask . $email;

 echo $maskedEmail; //your output
```